# PCL cloud visualization Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, point-cloud-library

I am trying to build this simple visualization example using VS2010:

http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/pcl_visualizer.php

I have linked all .lib files (both pcl and 3rdparty) however I get a bunch of unresolved external symbol errors all of which are happening on vtkRendering-gd.lib and seem to be OpenGL related like the following:

```
vtkRendering-gd.lib(vtkOpenGLTexture.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_glPopAttrib
vtkRendering-gd.lib(vtkOpenGLRenderer.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_glPopAttrib
vtkRendering-gd.lib(vtkOpenGLRepresentationPainter.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_glPopAttrib
vtkRendering-gd.lib(vtkOpenGLLight.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_glPopMatrix
```

I am on a x64 Windows 7 machine, and I have installed the x64 version of PCL using the all-in-one installer.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I had similar problem, and I tried very hard. Solving each problem makes another. The truth is, in my opinion, just move to linux if you can. Install an Ubuntu and then install PCL, it works perfectly.

Comment: I guess that's what I am going to do. Turns out that pcl + Visual Studio 10 + Win64 combination has a lot of issues. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

in the http://www.pointclouds.org/ it says that the visualization library is ment to work in Qt. It might be using Qt GUI features .any way I suggest you check if your error is coming from it.
(although I know that you could define your own GUI with other engines like opengl)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using VS10 + Win64 + pcl with no issues. But I used another way of installation.

I installed dependencies (http://www.pointclouds.org/downloads/windows.html) from column `Windows MSVC 2010 (64bit)`
In particular:

- boost 1.50.0
- Eigen 3.0.5
- FLANN 1.7.1
- VTK 5.8.0 with Qt support
- Qt 4.8.0
- QHull 2011.1 (6.2.0.1385)
- OpenNI OpenNI 1.5.4 (patched)
- OpenNI Sensor 5.1.0 (patched)

After installing them one after another I followed instructions on this page http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/compiling_pcl_windows.php#compiling-pcl-windows

And I had no problems, everything is working fine.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Jun. Could you please tell me which .lib files you specify in Linker->Input?

Comment: I use CMake for that. I think it is a much easier way to create a new project (especially for beginners, as this way is a default one and specified in tutorials). Should you have any troubles using CMake just ask, I'll try to expand my answer further then.

Comment: How did you use CMake to make projects ? Is this a question that you can help answer ? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45300979/viewing-3d-point-cloud-by-integrating-custom-c-api-with-generic-point-cloud-view

Answer (score 0):

You are missing opengl32.lib
Add it to Properties->Linker->Input->Additional Dependecies